# Python:'dict' object has no attribute 'iter'

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, waitress

I am using python 3.7.8 and trying to access azure data lake account files getting this error.

**dependencies version details:**

```
azure-core                  1.13.0
azure-storage-blob          12.8.1
azure-storage-file-datalake 12.2.0
Flask                       1.1.2
Flask-Cors                  3.0.10
waitress                    2.0.0
```

**apptest.py**

```
import json
from flask_cors import CORS
import base64
import sys

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient

from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient,generate_blob_sas, generate_account_sas, ResourceTypes, AccountSasPermissions,BlobSasPermissions

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True
CORS(app)
from waitress import serve


def get_service_client(requestPayLoad):
    try:  
        credentials=get_Credentials(requestPayLoad)
        service_client= DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="{}://{}.dfs.core.windows.net".format(
        "https", credentials['storage_account_name']), credential=credentials['storage_account_key'])
        return service_client
    except Exception as e:
     print(e)
def get_Credentials(requestPayLoad):
    storage_account_name= config['accountName'] if requestPayLoad["TypeOfData"]=='Private'else config['publicAccountName']
    storage_account_key= config['accountKey'] if requestPayLoad["TypeOfData"]=='Private'else config['publicAccountKey']
    return json.loads(json.dumps({"storage_account_name": storage_account_name, "storage_account_key": storage_account_key}))
```

**server error:**

```
[2021-08-13 09:35:56,632] ERROR in server: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iter'
ERROR:server:'dict' object has no attribute 'iter'
ERROR:waitress:Exception while serving /api/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/waitress/channel.py", line 397, in service
    task.service()
```

could you please help me to solve the error?

Thanks.

Comment: Get rid of the `try: except:` in order to properly see your error.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue is because of passing credentials as two parameters and formatting account_url.

Instead try to pass the parameters as below:

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient

service = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url="https://<my-storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/", credential=credential)
```

For more information about DataLakeServiceClient go through [Azure Python SDK Docs](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/python/azure-storage-file-datalake/12.0.0b5/index.html)

Also we can remove try except block to find the error trace or we can handle it in below way:

```
additional_data = {}
try:
    error_body = ContentDecodePolicy.deserialize_from_http_generics(storage_error.response)
    if error_body and hasattr(error_body, "iter"):
        for info in error_body:
            if info.tag.lower() == 'code':
                error_code = info.text
```

Please refer to the fixed issues in [GIT](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/pull/18147) for Dict Json errors

Comment: It seems there are syntax errors in your answer. You have repeated `if error_body`

Comment: Hey thanks, Updated my code, Also this is just an example to handle the exceptions if we have anything